# Spring Security Java Config same url allowed for anonymous user and for others authentication needed

Tags: spring, spring-security

In Spring Security Java Config

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.antMatcher("/guest/**").authenticated;

}
```

What if I want this same url to be allowed access to a particular principal or a User.

And others Authentication needed. Is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand: who exactly should be able to visit this url? To know that a user has some role the system has to authenticate them. Could you please rephrase the conditions?

Comment: AnonymousUser doesn't need any authentication, All other users need authentication

Comment: `http.antMatcher("/guest/**").permitAll()` will allow access to everyone: anonymous users (i.e. those who are not authenticated) and all the rest (i.e. the authenticated ones). Is this what you seek for?

Comment: We run our unit tests for API as an anonymous user, when we changed to Java Config this doesn't works. So authentication is need for all users except user is set as Anonymous

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely bypass any security checks for certain URLs, you could do the following:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    // configuring here URLs for which security filters
    // will be disabled (this is equivalent to using
    // security="none")
    web
        .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                    "/guest/**"
            )
    ;
}
```

This is equivalent to the following XML snippet:

```
<sec:http security="none" pattern="/guest/**" />
```

Comment: No, the same Url  need Authentication for All Users Except Anonymous user

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches; first, use HttpSecurity#not() like this to block anonymous users;

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/guest/**")
            .not().hasRole("ANONYMOUS");
    // more config
}
```

Or use something like ROLE_VIEW_GUEST_PAGES that gets added depending on the user type from your UserDetailsService.  This, IMO gives you better control over who sees guest pages.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/guest/**")
            .hasRole("VIEW_GUEST_PAGES");
    // more config
}
```